# Bootstrap Validator with datepicker does not validate date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, datepicker, bootstrapvalidator

I am using bootstrap validator to validate a form but I have been unable to get it to validate a text box that gets populated by datepicker.  When I click in the text box, datepicker displays a calendar.  I select a date and the text box gets populated with the selected date (the calendar does not auto-close which is another issue even though I modified the bootstrap-datepicker.js to have autoclose default to yes) but the validator seems to ignore the box.  It never changes to red or green and never gets a check or an x.  Any suggestions?

```html
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="test_file_upload.aspx.vb" Inherits="ARDirectWithMobile.test_file_upload" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title id="titleTag"><%: Page.Title %> 401(k) Account</title>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    <link runat="server" id="StyleLink1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="contactForm" runat="server" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">File Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 bs-example">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="uploadfile" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Navigate to the file you wish to upload" CssClass="label_under_text"></asp:Label> 
     </div>                          
    </div>

    <div class="date-form">   
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Pay Date</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 bs-example">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="PayDate" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></label>
                <input id="PayDate" type="text" class="form-control date-picker" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <br /><br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    <script>
        $(".date-picker").datepicker();
    </script>
    <script>
        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#contactForm').bootstrapValidator({
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {
                    uploadfile: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'You must select a valid payroll file to upload'
                            },
                            file: {
                                extension: 'txt,xls,csv',
                                type: 'text/plain,application/vnd.ms-excel,text/csv'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    PayDate: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The Pay Date is required and cannot be empty'
                            },
                            stringLength: {
                                max: 10,
                                minlength: 10,
                                message: 'The Pay Date must be 10 characters long'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: look for onChange event on plugin website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation will not work with input `id` only with `name` attribute and the datepicker input doesn't has the `name` attribute (or may be you forget it)

```
<input id="PayDate" name="PayDate" type="text" class="form-control date-picker" />
```

and you don't need to check the length of date, don't need following piece of code

```
stringLength: {
    max: 10,
    minlength: 10,
    message: 'The Pay Date must be 10 characters long'
}
```

and you are using `bootstrapdate picker`, to validate the date and and re-validate the date if change you need `changeDate` event

```
$('.date-picker').on('changeDate show', function(e) {
    $('#contactForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'PayDate');
});
```

So final Code will be

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".date-picker").datepicker();
 $('#contactForm').bootstrapValidator({
   feedbackIcons: {
  valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
  invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
  validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
   },
   fields: {
  uploadfile: {
    validators: {
   notEmpty: {
     message: 'You must select a valid payroll file to upload'
   },
   file: {
     extension: 'txt,xls,csv',
     type: 'text/plain,application/vnd.ms-excel,text/csv'
   }
    }
  },
  PayDate: {
    validators: {
   notEmpty: {
     message: 'The Pay Date is required and cannot be empty'
   },
   date: {
     format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
     message: 'The format is MM/DD/YYYY'
   }
    }
  }
   }
 });
 $('.date-picker').on('changeDate show', function(e) {
   $('#contactForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'PayDate');
 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<form id="contactForm" runat="server" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">File Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 bs-example">
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="uploadfile" />
      <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Navigate to the file you wish to upload" CssClass="label_under_text"></asp:Label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="date-form">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Pay Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 bs-example">
      <div class="input-group">
        <label for="PayDate" class="input-group-addon btn">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></label>
        <input type="text" id="PayDate" name="PayDate" class="form-control date-picker" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltuq9v67/4/)

Comment: The date is now being validated correct.  Thank you for this.  However, do you have any idea why when the date fails validation, the label, text box, and "x" mark remain a muted black, not the danger red like when the file name field fails validation?

Comment: you need to add the `form-group` and little bit css customization, it's because of `<span></span>` and datepicker and input `calendar icon` which causing the `error icon` not display at it's proper place and color of error not changing to red, check this fiddle and follow the code http://jsfiddle.net/Ltuq9v67/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#expiry_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    }).on('change', function(e) {
        // Revalidate the date field
        $('#frmForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'expiry_date');
    });
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please add an explanation of how this code is supposed to work and is a viable solution to the given question.